# A local/global variable in RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, javascript

I'd like to create a variable that will be accessible from any module inside my RequireJS project.

For example, on init I'd like to set:

```
this.myVar = 123;
```

and be able to access it in any other module inside (but not outside) my RequireJS project such as:

```
console.log(this.myVar);
```

Is this possible?

P.S - I'm using 'this' just for an example. Any other option is viable.

P.S 2 - The RequireJS is actually a widget that can be instantiated several times such as :

```
new Widget('w1');
new Widget('w2');
```

and the global parameter should be inside each instance and not shareable between them.

EDIT (Example for such possible code, which doesn't work):

```
define('module1', [], function() {
    var myVar = 123;
});

define('module2', ['module1'], function(m1) {
    console.log(myVar); // Should print '123'
});
```

Comment: `var myModuleScopedVariable = 123` ?

Comment: I Wish :) It doesn't work in other modules - just the current one.

Comment: I've added an example for the code

Comment: Create a `settings` module and whoever needs to access the settings imports it - have it export an object with whatever variables you want.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! Works perfectly! If you could write this as an answer - I could accept it :)

Comment: Sure, posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Settings` module and whoever needs to access the settings imports it - have it export an object with whatever variables you want.